# How to get the count of boolean value (if it is true) in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have to get the count of boolean value (if it is true) in array of objects.
The json structure is given below:

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "a",
    "select": true
  },

  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "b",
    "select": false
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "x",
    "select": true
  },

  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "y",
    "select": false
  }
]
```

Comment: downvoted because you didn't provide any attempt (code snippets) to solve your problem

Answer (score 9):

You can do it using **[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

Try like this

```
console.log(data.filter((x,i) => { return x.select; }).length)
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/0h60yyfj/3/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

That should do the trick. no angular needed

```
function getTrueCount(array) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].select) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). The code would be:

```
var truevalues = yourarray.filter(function(element) {
    return (element.select == true);
}
```

It returns the values that accomplish the condition, so the values that have select true. Then you can count the values using `truevalues.length`

Answer (score 1):

This is the functional programming way of doing it:

```
var count = yourarray.reduce((a, c) => c.yourboolvariable ? ++a : a, 0);
```

Explanation:
The zero at the end is the initial value of a. a is known as the accumulator. The "reduce" function iterates through each value in the array, passing in the accumulator "a" as well is the current item "c". The right size of the fat arrow is the return value. If yourboolvariable value is true, it will add 1 to a and return that. If yourboolvariable value is false, it will simply return the previous value of a, ready to be passed in to the next iteration. The final value of a becomes the result returned to count.

This is not angular. This is straight JavaScript.

Comment: What about the support on various browsers?

Comment: Chrome: Yes, Edge: yes, Firefox: 3, Internet Explorer: 9, Opera:10.5, Safari: 4, and you can use polyfills before that I believe.

Comment: You should update your answer instead of replying in the comment.

Comment: Really? I don't see anyone else putting what browsers their solution works with, and it was pretty easy just googling the answer.

Answer (score 0):

so ,
If it is response then 
you can use forEach loop like

```
$scope.count = 0;
angular.forEach(response, function(value, key) {
  if (value.select == true) {
    $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
  }
});
```

Then u can take `$scope.count` from here

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific JSON structure which you have mentioned then you can try something like this. Can use arrow function if you want

```
const getResult = function(inputArr){
    let result = [];
    if( Object.prototype.toString.call(inputArr) === '[object Array]' && inputArr.length > 0 ){
        result = inputArr.filter(function(item){
            return item.select;
        });
    }
    return result.length;
};
```