# Count number of True/False without `.reduce()`,`.filter()` `forEach()`

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

```
 var x = [true,false,true,false]
```

Is there a way to tell how many "True" are within an array?
 But without using `.reduce()`,`.filter()` `forEach()`:

[How to get the count of boolean value (if it is true) in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305454/how-to-get-the-count-of-boolean-value-if-it-is-true-in-array-of-objects)

[Count the number of true members in an array of boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317140/count-the-number-of-true-members-in-an-array-of-boolean-values)

Comment: Can you explain the restrictions? Can you use `some` or `every`? If there are restrictions on fairly obvious use cases, it helps to explain why they are there.

Comment: so what is wrong with the loop? Not sure what the select is supposed to be.

Comment: @Ryul, you can write a recursive function to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use casting boolean to number (true => 1,
 false => 0). Unary + before operand is used for this action:

```
const array = [true, false, true, false];

function getTrueCount(array) {
    let trueCount = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        trueCount += +(array[i]);
    }

    return trueCount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there can only be `true`/`false` elements, I guess you could `.join` and then check how many `true`s there are in the string with a regular expression:

```js
const getTrueCount = array => (array.join().match(/true/g) || []).length;
console.log(getTrueCount([true,false,true,false]));
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach would be to do it **recursively**, this uses no loops and no array methods:

```js
const countTrue = ([x, ...r]) => (+x || 0) + (r.length ? countTrue(r) : 0);

console.log(countTrue([true,false,true,false]));
console.log(countTrue([false,false,true,false]));
console.log(countTrue([false,false,false,false]));
console.log(countTrue([]));
```